# Stylize Radio Buttons using jQuery (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, radio-button

I have found an excellent tutorial for stylizing radio buttons. I can get to the point of getting the CSS part to work, but I am not strong in jquery/javascript. I'm attempting to create the effect by turning it into a WordPress plugin. Any help is appreciated.

Tutorial: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Turn-Radio-Buttons-Checkboxes-Into-Labels-zInput.html

Demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Turn-Radio-Buttons-Checkboxes-Into-Labels-zInput/

Adding the jquery code does not seem to allow for selecting anything. I do know a little and know that I need to change the $ to jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

And, even though I have been looking for hours, I stumbled upon an answer that worked.

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('input[type="radio"], label').addClass('stylized');

```
$('input').click(function () {
    $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("active");
    $('input:checked').parent().addClass("active");
});
```

});

So basically, I'm adding a stylized class to transform the buttons and the active class to only those selected items. Previous to this, I could do the active part, but it would not stick to a single radio button set.

Solution from nandokakimoto: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3376557/

On first click, an item from each is selected, so there is that one glitch.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLsej.png)

Comment: And the final code that made it all work, without any side effects:

`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('input[type="radio"], label').addClass('stylized');

    $('input').click(function () {
        $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("active");
        $(this).closest("label").addClass("active");
    });    
});`